# How to add multiple textviews in android

Tags: android, textview

I am making one chat application in this application I have to display all users names who are connected to login user,so I am showing this data in dialog,actually problem is different text views with different styles in relative layout which wiil be arranged automatically side by side,if layout width occupied by 3 text views remaining two text views should be in third line like that.please help me

ex:

1. car bus bicycle
2. train ship bike
3. aeroplane

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/categoriesContainer"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
     android:background="@color/view_background"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/tagsTitle"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
         android:text="@string/title"
         android:textColor="@color/view_title"
         android:textSize="18sp" />

     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/tagsContainer"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="left"
         android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
         android:gravity="left"
         android:orientation="vertical" />
 </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="2dp" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/categoryIndications"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/xml_category_count_bubble"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:minWidth="20dp"
    android:padding="4dip"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/categoryName"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/xml_category_name_bubble"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:minWidth="40dp"
    android:padding="4dip"
    android:textColor="@color/view_text"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

And this:

```
private void setTags(){

    LinearLayout tagsContainer;

    // Categories
    tagsContainer = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tagsContainer);
    // Container of the tags
    tagsContainer.removeAllViews();
    tagsContainer.refreshDrawableState();
    // Indicate category layout
    LinearLayout indicateLayout = (LinearLayout) 
            LayoutInflater.from(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.message_indicate_category, null);

    if(YOUR_TEXTVIEW_STRINGS_ARRAY.size()>0){
        Button textButton;
        LinearLayout tag;
        for(int i = 0; i<YOUR_TEXTVIEW_STRINGS_ARRAY.size();i++){
            // View of the tag
            tag = (LinearLayout) 
                    LayoutInflater.from(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).
                    inflate(R.layout.customview_tag, null);
            textButton= (Button)tag.findViewById(R.id.categoryName);
            textButton.setText(YOUR_TEXTVIEW_STRINGS_ARRAY..get(i));    
            textButton = (Button)tag.findViewById(R.id.categoryIndications);
            textButton.setText(YOUR_TEXTVIEW_STRINGS_ARRAY.get(i));         

            tagsContainer.addView(tag);
        }       
    }
    else{
        // View of the tag
        indicateLayout = (LinearLayout) 
                LayoutInflater.from(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.message_indicate_category, null);  
        tagsContainer.addView(indicateLayout);
    }

}
```